# how to change background color for nimbus look and feel using java

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

In Java Swing application, I am trying nimbus look and feel. It looks excellent in JdesktopPane control but i want the different color for my all desktoppane but theme is fine.

Is there any way to change the background color of nimbus look and feel?

Here is the sample code to apply the nimbus look and feel.

```
   try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
          if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
         }
        }
       }  
     catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("control", new Color(...))
```

from the [l&f tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: @user1960524 before set l&f

Comment: it worked for me thanks a lot can i have two look and feel in a single project

Answer (score 2):

Nimbus paints the background using what looks like vector type drawing routines to paint a fancy background pattern. 
To change the background of JDesktopPane in case of nimbus you need to chang the background Painter used by the JDesktopPane to simply fill the pane with the background color that you need (say gray).And then set the `"DesktopPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter"` propery with that Painter object.
For example watch the code given below:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import com.sun.java.swing.Painter;
import java.awt.Color;

public class NimbusFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JDesktopPane desktop;
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        desktop = new MyDesktopPane();
        getContentPane().add(desktop);
        setSize(300,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    class MyDesktopPane extends JDesktopPane
    {
        @Override
        public void updateUI() 
        {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName())) 
            {
                UIDefaults map = new UIDefaults();
                Painter<JComponent> painter = new Painter<JComponent>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, int w, int h) 
                    {
                        g.setColor(Color.gray);
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
                    }
                };
                map.put("DesktopPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", painter);
                putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", map);
            }
            super.updateUI();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        try
        {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) 
            {
                    if ("Nimbus".equalsIgnoreCase(info.getName())) 
                {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                NimbusFrame frame = new NimbusFrame();
                frame.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```